# Predicate splitting and parallel processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm new to Spring Batch, and I don't know how to come up with the right solution for my problem.

I have a CSV file of a million or two of records. These records are grouped by an id.

> id;head-x;head-y;...
> 1;;;
> 1;;;
> 1;;;
> ...
> 1;;;
> 2;;;
> 2;;;
> 2;;;
> ...
> 2;;;
> 3;;;
> 3;;;
> ...
> 3;;;
> ...
> ...

What I want is to process this records as group. I read all the 1 group records process and convert them to a business model and save it to my database.

I need to do this work in parallel to speed up processing. I want to process 2 and 3 if possible at the same time of 1.

I've started with using `StepBuilderFactory#chunk()` but this gives me a fixed size of chunks. I can get multiple groups inside a chunk or an uncomplete one.

Have you any idea to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your records are already grouped by Id in that order, you can use a [SingleItemPeekableItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SingleItemPeekableItemReader.html) that reads multiple physical records by Id into a single logical item. Once this in place, you can synchronize the reader (to make it thread-safe) and configure a multi-threaded step to process items in parallel.

You can also take a look at the [AggregateItemReader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.java) (which is part of the samples) to aggregate multiple physical records into a single logical one: [multi-line orders sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#multiline). Here too a multi-threaded step would improve the performance of your job.

Comment: The link to the sample is a working code example. What is missing in this answer to be accepted?